# How to estimate population size, recapture rate and survival probability with spatial CJS model

Tags: r, population, ecology

I would like to ask for some help. I am new to data analyses in R and I need some help with my current analyses. I need to make a spatial CJS model with normal dispersal to estimate population size, recapture rate and survival probability on my data but I can not find a script for it. Can somebody provide me with one, please ? One article about it was suggested to me but because I just started learning R I can not write the script myself (Schaub and Royle, Methods in Ecology and Evolution 2014, 5, 1316–1326, doi: 10.1111/2041-210X.12134).

I tried to look up some scripts for spatial CJS model with normal dispersal to run my data through it but can not find one.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem. I found this R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openCR/ , maybe there are others. You might try organizing the equations from the paper into just what you need for the analysis you want to do, and then ask for help to translate each one. I think focusing attention on just the parts you need help with might help others help you.